# Features 8.x-3.7 not writable on Window's Ubuntu

Tags: features, files

8x-3.7 features, most stable version, but I am having trouble writing to custom module on the UI. My structure is as follow:

```
 -modules/
    contrib/
       features/
    custom/
       news_blogs/
          config/
             install/
                [code]
```

when i edit my view, i go to `/admin/config/development/features` I see that the feature state is  edit. I click the checkbox and click `write`.

I get error:
`Package News/Blogs not written to modules/custom/news_blogs. Error: Failed to create directory /mnt/c/mywebsite/modules/custom/news_blogs/config/install..` and then inside `install` code is deleted and empty.

I check my logs: 
`Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->mkdir() (line 226 of /mnt/c/mywebsite/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php) #0...`

I checked my permissons and it is 777 and my usr is the owner for the directory.
I am unsure what else to check or test to figure out what can be going wrong. Any help is thanked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using something like a virtual machine (Vagrant?) with a shared windows file system.  The problem is that Windows permissions don't map well to Linux ones.  That is why the chmod error is happening.

You may need to get your webserver running under the same user you share the file system under, e.g. the vagrant user.

Personally, I have never gotten a stable way to have Features write to a windows share. There always seemed to be a gotcha in the ones that worked.  I've just excepted that I had to download the feature archive, unpack it, and copy it to the site on the Windows side.

But your situation may be different.

Comment: I found this forum very helpful: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/81